# How to reduce boilerplate dealing with Maybe and lists?

Tags: haskell

Is there a cleaner way to compose functions producing lists with other producing `Maybe`s?

```
import Text.Feed.Query (getItemLink, getFeedItems)

s = getFeedItems >=> (maybeToList . getItemLink)
```

Comment: You could use [mapMaybe](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:mapMaybe) or [catMaybes](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:catMaybes) from `Data.Maybe`.

Comment: Where's the boilerplate?

Comment: @NikitaVolkov Only in Haskell is 40 non-whitespace characters considered boilerplate.  Besides bennofs managed to get it down to 33 characters, that's a whole 7 characters of savings!

Comment: I recommend `(<=<)` instead of `(>=>)` so that the pipeline consistently reads right to left.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`mapMaybe :: (a -> Maybe b) -> [a] -> [b]`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:mapMaybe) from `Data.Maybe`:

```
s = mapMaybe getItemLink . getFeedItems
```

That module also contains another useful function, `catMaybes`:

```
catMaybes :: [Maybe a] -> [a] -- filter out all the Nothings
```

List comprehensions are also useful in this case, although more verbose:

```
s feed = [ itemLink | Just itemLink <- map getItemLink (getFeedItems feed) ]
-- s feed = [ itemLink | item <- getFeedItems feed, Just itemLink <- return item ]
```